# need help with jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have created an accordion menu. Here is my js code:

```
var menu = $('ul.menu', '#sidebar');

menu.accordion({
    header: '.parent > a',
    collapsible: true
});
```

Here is a recreation of what we have:
http://jsfiddle.net/chMPT/

Here's my delima: I want the menu to be completely collapsed by default and I can't change the html structure because the menu is produced by joomla.

I tried using the create method to close the active menu upon the creation of the accordion but it doesn't work right. And here's that code:

```
var menu = $('ul.menu', '#sidebar');

menu.accordion({
   create: function(event, ui) {
        menu.accordion("activate" , false);
    },
    header: '.parent > a',
    collapsible: true
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its as simple as

```
menu.accordion({
    header:'.parent > a',
    collapsible: true,
    active:false
});
```

EDIT: [link to jQuery UI doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active) regarding the active option

Comment: Excellent. Classic case of me thinking to hard to the the answer sitting right in front of me! Really appreciate the jsfiddle link as well.